Introducing StackPulse: a real-time Cross-platform Stack Overflow question notifier
Screenshot

I'm excited to share a new tool I've been working on called StackPulse. It's designed to help developers stay on top of new questions in their areas of expertise on Stack Overflow.
About
What is StackPulse?
StackPulse is a cross-platform application that provides real-time notifications for new Stack Overflow questions based on tags you're interested in. It's built with Flutter and works on Windows, macOS, (Linux not yet), Android, iOS, and web browsers.
Key Features:

Real-time notifications for new questions
Customizable tag following
Cross-platform support (desktop, mobile, and web)
Lightweight and efficient
Open-source

How it works:

You add tags you're interested in (e.g., 'flutter', 'python', 'react')
The app connects to Stack Overflow's WebSocket
When a new question with your tags appears, you get an instant notification
Click the notification to open the question in your browser

Why I built this:
As a developer, I often found myself constantly refreshing Stack Overflow to catch new questions I could answer. StackPulse automates this process, allowing you to be one of the first to see and potentially answer new questions in your areas of expertise.
Technical Details:

Built with Flutter
Uses WebSocket for real-time updates
Implements platform-specific notification services
Stores preferences locally for persistence

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/mendelg/stackpulse
Download
Visit the web app:

https://mendelg.github.io/stackpulse/

Or:
Download now

Support
I'm looking for feedback, feature suggestions, and contributors. If you're interested in trying it out or contributing to the project, please check out the GitHub repo.
Questions for the community:

What features would you like to see added?
Have you encountered any issues with cross-platform notifications that I should be aware of?
Any suggestions for improving the user experience?

Thanks for checking out StackPulse. I'm looking forward to your thoughts and feedback!
